# How to (in a shell script) get the position of a substring that contains double quotes?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a very long string and I want to find the first occurrence of a substring - but the substring contains double quotes. The only way of doing this that I'm familiar with is:

```
mystr='a very, very, extremely, incredibly long string of text that contains the phrase he said, "Hello!" somewhere in the middle'
strpos=`expr index "$mystr" Hello`
echo $strpos
```

which returns 92. But that won't work if the substring contains double quotes...

```
strpos=`expr index "$mystr" he said, "Hello`
```

I've tried escaping the double quotes (and the spaces). I've tried wrapping the string to find with single quotes. If I manage to run it without getting "unexpected EOF" or "syntax error", it returns a preposterous result like "2". (The position is somewhere in the thousands.) I'm guessing that I can't do what I'm trying to do with `expr index` but if not, then how *can* I do it?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not trying to echo "Hello!". I'm trying to get just the starting position of the substring within the main string - and have that number assigned to a variable.

Comment: the `expr` man page says `index STRING CHARS` gives the "index in STRING where any CHARS is found, or 0". That is, it looks for any of the given _characters_, not a full substring. `expr index foobar bo` gives 2 (the first `o`), `expr index 'foo"bar' '"'` gives 4 (the first quote) and `expr index 'foo"bar' '"foo"'` gives 1 (the very first `f`). What are you trying to do in the end? There might be some other way to do that without getting the actual position of the substring.

Answer (score 2):

I think that it searches for characters of second string in first one. You can use grep

```
mystr='a very, very, extremely, incredibly long string of text that contains 2 the phrase he said, "Hello!" somewhere in the middle'
echo "$mystr"| grep -o -b Hello!
```

It will return `91:Hello!`. Here indexing starts from 0.

If there are multiple occurrences like of a, then output will be

```
0:a 58:a 65:a 77:a 85:a
```

If you want to search double quotes too, then escape them,

```
echo "$mystr"| grep -o -b \"Hello!\"
```

The output will be

```
90:"Hello!"
```

Comment: This will fail if there's another "Hello!" in the string, as OP's requirement is the *first* occurrence. You can use then `head -1` to get it. I'm borrowing the `-b` for my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Only with Parameter Expansion :

```
mystr='a very, very, extremely, incredibly long string of text that contains the phrase he said, "Hello!" somewhere in the middle'  
searchstr='"Hello!"'
newstr="${mystr%%$searchstr*}"
echo "position = $((${#newstr} + 1))"
```

Comment: This is the optimal one liner answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's see if this is what you are looking for:

```
mystr='a very, very, extremely, incredibly long string of text that contains the phrase he said, "Hello!" somewhere in the middle'

$ var=$(echo "$mystr" | grep -o -b "Hello!" | head -1)
$ echo "$var"
91:Hello!
$ pos="${var%:*}"
$ echo "$pos"
91
```

Comment: What does 'head -1' do? because there are 30 occurrences of the substring within the main string. Your code finds the 29th one.

Comment: `head -1` prints the first result of the grep command. If in your case it doesn't there must be something different in the string and/or the command. Is the real string too long? If not, you can post it along with the command you used.

Comment: Nope, it's all good. The occurences got reordered so it's working properly. Thanks for the help!